# VSTS - Archive DotNet Build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm learning about build pipelines in VSTS. I'm trying to 1) build a "hello world" .NET project and 2) zip up the executable. At this time, I have a build pipeline with two tasks. Those two tasks are defined like this:

**.NET Core**

```
Command: build
Path to Project(s): ./MyConsoleApp/MyConsoleApp.csproj
Arguments: --configuration Release --runtime linux-x64
```

**Archive Files**

```
Root folder or file to archive: $(Build.BinariesDirectory)
Prepend root folder or file to archive paths: checked
Archive file to create: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyConsoleApp.zip
```

I then have a task that uploads the file to AWS. This build pipeline successfully runs. The build task (.NET Core) build successfully with no errors or warnings. The archive files task successfully creates the .zip file. I can see the .zip file in AWS. However, when I download the .zip file, it's kind of empty. The only thing that's in it is a directory named "b". I was expecting to see the contents of `bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\linux-x64`.

What am I missing? Where are the files associated with my build?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you validate that your build output is actually being placed in `$(Build.BinariesDirectory)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the `--output` flag on your `dotnet build` command and specify an output location of `$(Build.BinariesDirectory)`.